# How to move an image from one position to another with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am relatively a newbie in the field of CSS. I have seen the @KEYFRAME element for displaying an animation that moves from one side to another. But I was just wondering how is it possible to move an image(in terms of an animation) that moves from one side to another as the page loads?

All answers are appreciated in advance
Thanks

```
       div
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst
    {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes myfirst
    {
    0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far

Comment: @Israel Cohen You can do this using jquery...:)

Answer (score 4):

Please check the following fiddle for a back and forth image animation http://jsfiddle.net/jHHnN/ In the html apply the class "imganim" to the image tag and add the below CSS

```
 .imganim
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst
    {
    0%   { left:0px; top:0px;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)}
    50%  {left:100%; margin-left:-100px;-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg)}
    }

    /* Standard syntax */
    @keyframes myfirst
    {
    0%   { left:0px; top:0px;transform:rotate(0deg)}
    50%  {left:100%; margin-left:-100px;transform:rotate(360deg)}
    100% {left:0px; top:0px;transform:rotate(0deg)}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer right and a vote up, just a small tip the positioning can also be changed via the translateX or TranslateY values

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform css3 property

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/R65pL/

```
<span>
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1134660580/Puerco_Potter.jpg" alt="">
</span>


span{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    display inline-block;
}
img{
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    -ms-transition: all .4se;
    -o-transition: all .4s;
    transition: all .4s;
}
img:hover{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(20px);
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
    transform: translateX(20px);
}
```

see more in : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 0):

clock [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) ho read a complete guide about css animations.